# Add Placeholder to UITextField, how to set the placeholder text programmatically in swift?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, placeholder

I'm pulling out a phone number from a database, and when the user begins editing in the text field to change that phone number I'd like to use the number I currently have in the database as the placeholder.  Since this information changes with each user, how can I set it programmatically in swift?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to get the phone number from your database first (convert them to String), then you set `placeholder` of your `textField` to that String, like so

```
 textField.placeholder = phoneNumberString
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 3**

If your textField has text, you need to first set text property to nil, then set placeholder text:

```
textField.text = nil
textField.placeholder = "My Placeholder Text"
```

Answer (score 5):

Important to note for anyone else reading this, setting placeholder text in the main.storyboard seems to nullify this solution, so I had to first clear out my placeholders in the storyboard before implementing this.  Once that was done @Khuong and @Himanshu's answer worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Fetch your desired data from your database (Core data) and after converting it into string format... say phoneString

use this line to set this string as a placeholder text

```
phoneTextField.placeholder = phoneString
```

Answer (score 2):

**Apply this line of code in to View Did Load**

```
new_Password.attributedPlaceholder =
            NSAttributedString(string: " New Password", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]) // new_Password : our text feild name
```

Comment: this is what worked for me, its very strange, to set placeHolder to empty string `fieled?.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString()`

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C code:

```
[usernameText setPlaceholder:@"My Placeholder Text"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to say if you have changed your textfield's text and background colors programmatically, you can't do that with the placeholder text's colors and must set up an Attributed Placeholder instead. This is a problem if your device is in put in "dark mode" and are trying to make a non-dark mode screen by hand - you might not be able to see the placeholder!