# How to change placeHolder text of UItextField programmatically if I have designed textField in XIB

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have to make a custom class to design `textField` in `XIB` and reuse it multiple times in my `viewController`. I want to change each placeholder name programmatically.

Comment: provide code that you tried

Comment: @IBInspectable var placeHolderText: String = "" {
        didSet{
        rsFloatingView.placeHolderStringKey = placeHolderText
        }
   }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Placeholder to UITextField, how to set the placeholder text programmatically in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995356/add-placeholder-to-uitextfield-how-to-set-the-placeholder-text-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

Create subclass as:

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    }

    func placeHolderColor(pColor: UIColor, pText: String) {

        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: pText,
                                                               attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: pColor])

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an open variable of type string in your textfield custom class. Access that variable to change a placeholder name where ever implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can change by following two way

1) `yourTextField.placeholder = "some string"`

2) `yourTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "some string")`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the placeholder you can use the below code

```
yourTextField.attributedPlaceholder =
            NSAttributedString(string: "YourText", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white])
```

Answer (score 0):

try making a custom uitextfield class

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var TFPlaceholder: String? {
        willSet {
            self.placeholder = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Goodluck!! :)

Answer (score 0):

for swift > 5.0

```
 class CustomTextField: UITextField {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

func placeHolderColor(pColor: UIColor, pText: String) {
          self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(pText,
                attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: pColor])
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in Xcode 13 and swift 5. Try this :

```
yourTextfield.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "yourPlaceholderText")
```